# How to pass an OAuth2 access token as a variable in a get request?

Tags: python, request

I am trying to figure out the api of a survey tool our company is using.
I am new to this whole thing so I this is propably very basic, but googling didnt get me anywhere.
My issue is that I am able to retrieve an access token, but I cannot figure out how to pass it properly in the get request.

The only thing that worked for me so far is simply copy pasting the actual access token, which for automation purposes is of course not a viable option. From googling it seems like I should be able to pass it as a variable aswell, but I was not able to do so.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


client_id='XXX'
client_secret='XXX'


auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
access_token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://test.com/api/token', auth=auth)


hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token'}

payload = {'surveyid': 'XXX'}

r = requests.get('https://test.com/api/results', params=payload, headers=hed)
```

Comment: `hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}`? Thing is that you're not actually passing a variable the way you're doing it, you're passing the literal string `Bearer access_token`

Comment: @Edo Akse thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this is not working for me. It gives me the msg: 'the access token provided is invalid' code 401. Again if I do a print on this and copy paste the raw string of the access code like so: hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 12341251215'} it works.

Answer (score 0):

access_token = 'access token here as a variable'

api_url = "https://test.com/api/token"

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token}

payload = {

}